What are the exact block numbers and timestamps for Ethereum Sepolia hard forks?
I am looking for the precise block numbers and timestamps for all hard forks that occurred on the Ethereum Sepolia testnet.
Despite searching through online resources, I haven't been able to find a definitive list for Sepolia. Could anyone provide this information or point me to a reliable source?
